# ByteBuddy agent to replace one method param with another

Tags: java, byte-buddy, javaagents

I have a large 3rd party code base I can't modify, but I need to make a small but important change in many different places. I was hoping to use a ByteBuddy based agent, but I can't figure out how. The call I need to replace is of the form:

```
SomeSystemClass.someMethod("foo")
```

and I need to replace it with

```
SomeSystemClass.someMethod("bar")
```

while leaving all other calls to the same method untouched

```
SomeSystemClass.someMethod("ignore me")
```

Since `SomeSystemClass` is a JDK class, I do not want to advise it, but only the classes that contain calls to it. How can this be done?

Note that:

1. `someMethod` is static and
2. the calls (at least some of them) are inside a static initializer block

Comment: Check every class if it has that call.

Comment: Exactly. How do I do that?

Comment: See for example https://gist.github.com/raphw/34c0e2fffe2ee7b4f02f - A short google search yielded that.

Comment: I could really do without the passive aggressive tone, because I've googled a lot. And while I found many other examples, none seemed to fit my use case. But thanks for this, I'll try it out.

Comment: I just did a google search for by "bytebuddy agent intercept class load", and this was the first result. Did a short look over the code, seemed similar to the problem at hand and posted it. With a disclaimer that I didn't dig too much into it. Just to be called passive aggressive. Why do people always have to assume that that a comment is snarky, passive aggressive, or somehow attack them?

Comment: OK sorry. It's been a long day. Again, thanks, and stay healthy.

Comment: A bit of background: I don't like bytebuddy. It's fluent api confuses me. Which I guess is fine. Just a personal preference. If I had to solve this problem, I would write a Java agent that install a ClassFileTransformer, where I would use ASM to find the method calls and replace them. So, no idea how to do that with ByteBuddy. But I know that ByteBuddy can do it, so maybe my background helped me with finding the right keywords for the search. And I just grabbed the first link. But also did not want to post it as "here is the solution, use that", but as "ok, found that, might be useful".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211406/discussion-between-sean-patrick-floyd-and-johannes-kuhn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to this with Byte Buddy:

1. You transform all classes with the call site in question:

   ```
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
      .type(nameStartsWith("my.lib.pkg."))
      .transform((builder, type, loader, module) -> builder.visit(MemberSubstitution.relaxed()
         .method(SomeSystemClass.class.getMethod("someMethod", String.class))
         .replaceWith(MyAlternativeDispatcher.class.getMethod("substitution", String.class)
         .on(any()))
       .installOn(...);
   ```

   In this case, I suggest you to implement a class `MyAlternativeDispatcher` to your class path (it can also be shipped as part of the agent unless you have a more complex class loader setup such as OSGi where you implement the conditional logic:

   ```
    public class MyAlternativeDispatcher {
      public static void substitution(String argument) {
        if ("foo".equals(argument)) {
          argument = "bar";
        }
        SomeSystemClass.someMethod(argument);
      }
    }
   ```

   Doing so, you can set break points and implement any complex logic without thinking too much of byte code after setting up the agent. You can, as suggested, even ship the substitution method independently of the agent.
2. Instrument the system class itself and make it caller sensitive:

   ```
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
      .with(RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
       .disableClassFormatChanges()
      .type(is(SomeSystemClass.class))
      .transform((builder, type, loader, module) -> builder.visit(Advice.to(MyAdvice.class).on(named("someMethod").and(takesArguments(String.class)))))
       .installOn(...);
   ```

   In this case, you'd need to reflect on the caller class to make sure you only alter behavior for the classes you want to apply this change for. This is not uncommon within the JDK and since `Advice` inlines ("copy pastes") the code of your advice class into the system class, you can use the JDK internal APIs without restriction (Java 8 and prior) if you cannot use the stack walker API (Java 9 and later):

   ```
    class MyAdvice {
      @Advice.OnMethodEnter
      static void enter(@Advice.Argument(0) String argument) {
        Class<?> caller = sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass(1); // or stack walker
        if (caller.getName().startsWith("my.lib.pkg.") && "foo".equals(argument)) {
          argument = "bar";
        }
      }
    }
   ```

Which approach should you choose?

The first approach is probably more reliable but it is rather costly since you have to process all classes in a package or subpackages. If there are many classes in this package you will pay quite a price for processing all these classes to check for relevant call sites and therefore delay application startup. Once all classes are loaded, you have however paid the price and everything is in place without having altered a system class. You do however need to take care of class loaders to make sure that your substitution method is visible to everybody. In the simplest case, you can use the `Instrumentation` API to append a jar with this class to the boot loader what makes it globally visible.

With the second approach, you only need to (re-)transform a single method. This is very cheap to do but you will add a (minimal) overhead to every call to the method. Therefore, if this method is invoked a lot on a critical execution path, you'd pay a price on every invocation if the JIT does not discover an optimization pattern to avoid it. I'd prefer this approach for most cases, I think, a single transformation is often more reliable and performant.

As a third option, you could also use `MemberSubstitution` and add your own byte code as a replacement (Byte Buddy exposes ASM in the `replaceWith` step where you can define custom byte code instead of delegating). This way, you could avoid the requirement of adding a replacement method and just add the substitution code in-place. This does however bear the serious requirement that you:

- do not add conditional statements
- recompute the stack map frames of the class

The latter is required if you add conditional statements and Byte Buddy (or anybody) cannot optimize it in-method. Stack map frame recomputation is very expensive, fails comparable often and can require class loading locks to dead lock. Byte Buddy optimizes ASM's default recomputation, trying to avoid dead locks by avoiding class loading but there is no guarantee either, so you should keep this in mind.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll try out both approaches, thanks. Unfortunately the "unless you have a more complex class loader setup" is true, this is a JBoss / Wildfly environment, if that makes a difference. Anyway, this should suffice to get me started and I'll post follow-up questions if I get stuck.

Comment: So, I got the first approach to work in a unit test, which is a great step forward. But is it possible to pass in the original method as a parameter to the dispatcher method? I tried adding a parameter annotated `@net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice.Origin` but when I do, the instrumentation fails. Is there a way I can do MethodDelegation here, rather than static replacement?

Comment: delegation won't work with redefinition. Advice annotations are only for advice, not for substitution. You can use the chained step in MemberSubstitution to include custom method calls but it would require you to write ASM for that. There will be a convenience API but I have not had the time. Alternatively, use a stack walker as suggested with advice.

Comment: In-method replacements are the most complex operations. They are not in overly high demand, that's why I have not focused on them as much yet, but the convenience API I have in mind would make this easy and safe to do. If you don't mind working with Strings, Javassist might offer what you ate looking for by its ExpressionEditor.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that also